# Expo-av shows black screen when for multiple instances of video on 1 screen ( on Android TV )

Tags: react-native, video, expo, exoplayer, expo-av

Following is the flow of the application :-

1. All the video related data is fetched via api to the app
2. The app then downloads the video and store it the the FileSystem.documentDirectory ( I need these videos when the device is not connect to the internet so that I can play videos from the documentDirectory when the android tv is launched )
3. The downloaded video is then passed to components that have one or multiple video instances divided into sections or layout.

Following are the issues faced :-

1. The video runs perfectly when the app is launched for the first time. But whenever new data is loaded it loads few of the video instances and shows black screen for other ( the expo-av show that the video is loaded and has started on load ).
   2.This issue is seen in the log when we implement the onError method for expo-av : com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: Decoder init failed: OMX.MS.AVC.Decoder, Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [1280, 720, 23.976023], [-1, -1])

NOTE : I am trying to display the videos in the following layout on the Android TV via the app :-

1. 50% by 50%
2. 50% ( potrait ) by ( 25% by 25% ) landscape
3. 25% x 4 ( This is the major layout where I face this issue )